# IPv6 for Dlink DIR-816

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router, ipv6

Today I purchased Dlink dir-816 dual band AC router assuming it supports IPv6. But it doesn't support IPv6 as said by support person. The man who sold me this router also doesn't want to take it back. Is there a way to get IPv6 in this router   http://dlink.co.in/products/?pid=DIR-816 this link is the product and its information..

Comment: What makes you think the DIR-816 does not support IPv6?

Comment: their is no section of ipv6 itself in the router page.. and even the support person also told it doesn't support

Comment: I don't know where you're from, but here in the Netherlands, shops are required by law to have a period of time where the customer can get a complete refund, given that the device is not having any usage traces.

Comment: @shravansharma - The "support" person gave you bad advice.  the [DIR-816L](http://support.dlink.com/ProductInfo.aspx?m=DIR-816L), *Wireless AC750 Dual Band Cloud Router*, supports IPv6 because it's datasheet indicates it is **IPv6 ready**

Comment: but here in india.. theres no such law for me to make it possible.. can you give any better solution because I have an old dlink dir 600m that supports ipv6 and the support person is not even aware of this

Comment: sorry but mine is dlink dir-816... and 816L do support ipv6

Comment: @shravansharma - So provide us the specifications to the router in question, because I can't access the website you provided, so I don't have access to it's specifications.

Comment: ok.. it is a dual band router which has 3 external antennas giving great coverage.. so I choosed this router..

Comment: @shravansharma - Update your question with a working link to the datasheet that indicates there is no support for IPv6.  Even the DIR-815 supported IPv6 so I am having trouble accepting the DIR-816 doesn't while the DIR-816L does given the only difference appears to be the fact the DIR-816 is the regional model for India

Comment: I've worked with ipv6 before - and your ISP needs to support it. *or* you need to set up a tunnel.

Amusingly, I have a ISP that supports IPv6 and their own support dosen't know about it.  You might want to add that your old router worked with ipv6 and what connection method you used in your question.

Comment: I used ipv6 in ipv4 tunnel using tunnelbroker.net website.. and I was getting ipv6 through my router to all connected clients with old dlink dir-600m.. but don't know how to get this dlink dir -816  working on ipv6

Comment: @shravansharma - If your previous router/ISP supported IPv6 you shouldn't have had to use that tunnel service.  Are you 100% sure your ISP actually supports IPv6?

Comment: ya my ISP doesn't support ipv6 but I was interested to  learn that new version.. where my router supported creating a tunnel without any issue..

Answer (score 0):

> Today I purchased Dlink dir-816 dual band AC router assuming it
>   supports IPv6.

If the specifications and datasheet documentation do not match the Dlink DIR-816L then you assumed incorrectly.  The "support" person in that case gave you correct information. it appears only the [DIR-816L](http://support.dlink.com/ProductInfo.aspx?m=DIR-816L) and not the DIR-815, *Wireless AC750 Dual Band Cloud Router*, supports IPv6 because it's datasheet indicates it is **IPv6 ready**

[image]

- [Wireless AC750 Dual Band Cloud Router Specifications](http://support.dlink.com/ProductInfo.aspx?m=DIR-816L)
- [DIR-816L Wireless AC750 Dual Band Cloud Router Datesheet](http://content.us.dlink.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/DIR-816L_REVB_DATASHEET_1.00_EN.pdf)

> Is there a way to get IPv6 in this router

Your router does not appear to support it.

Comment: my router is DLINK-DIR 816......... and the above picture is for DLINK -Dir816L

Answer (score -1):

You can check the DD-WRT website and see if the website has the FW for the DIR-816 that supports the IPv6 modified base on the DIR-816's GPL source code